# Assigning value to checkboxes through ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I have a checkbox that I want to have a value=0. I have also assigned a ng-moel to it

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-group inline form-control" value="0" name="" id="deletelanguage" ng-show="IsVisible" ng-model="delStat">
```

The scope in my controller looks like this.

```
$scope.delStat="";
```

I want to changed the value of the checkbox to 1 if it is checked. How can I do that?

Comment: check [angular doc for checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: [`ngTrueValue` `ngFalseValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Answer (score 2):

Use  `ng-true-value  ng-false-value`   like below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-group inline form-control" ng-true-value='1'  id="deletelanguage" ng-show="IsVisible" ng-model="delStat">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" ng-true-value='1'  ng-false-value='0'  ng-model="val">Check</input>
   <br>Seleted Value :{{val}}
  </body>

</html>
```